# How many different values for $5$ different numbers multiplying?

Tags: statistics

For example you have $2,3,4,5,6$ how many different numbers can you make by combining up to $5$ of them together in multiplication?
$2\times3\times4\times5$ is one number, $2\times3$ is another, $5$ is another, and so on....

What is the formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically, we get $2^{|S|} - |S| - 1$ different piles of more than one number to multiply together.  Unfortunately, it's possible to get the same product many ways.  For instance, in the given example, $2\times6 = 3\times4$ and even better $2\times3 = 6$.  This is hard to deal with automatically; in fact, there's a somewhat similar problem called the *subset sum* problem that is known to be very computationally complex.  In this particular case, we get $32-5-1=26$ subsets, but only 21 distinct results: $12=2\times6=3\times4$, $24=2\times3\times4=4\times6$, $30=2\times3\times5=5\times6$, $60=2\times5\times6=3\times4\times5$, and $120=2\times3\times4\times5=4\times5\times6$ all appear twice.